# Stripe .NET - How to connect with card readers for simple transactions

Tags: .net, api

I'm rather new to the Stripe .NET API. At the moment I'm looking to integrate functionality for a .NET app to connect to a terminal reader via Stripe .NET.
My question is- what is the general flow of initialising, connecting to and interfacing with card readers?

I'm utilising the *Stripe.Terminal* namespace and followed through the documentation for some of the core functionalities listed, but I wanted to understand the best practices for setting up the flow for simple transactions, coming off from subtotals provided by a preceeding POS functionality, within a local-setting (i.e. the card readers could be used in a store or other physical location). Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripes .NET SDK doesn't support in person payments. One way around this is to use Stripe Terminal's REST API. If you're stuck reach out to support - they may be able to add you to the beta.

Comment: Thanks! I did figure-as-much, but yeah Terminal would be the way forward in this regard, thanks again.